# kubectl format output of get-contexts

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to format the output of the following command:

```
kubectl config get-contexts
```

so add a delimiter so i can parse it, i've tried YAML And Json but they aren't supported.

How can I format the data to be as follows:

```
CURRENT,NAME,CLUSTER,AUTHINFO,NAMESPACE,
,name1,cluster1,,clusterUser,,
*,name2,cluster2,clusterUser,,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably too late, but here's a PowerShell alternative that worked for me:

```
(kubectl config get-contexts | Out-String) -replace ' +', ','
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 4):

You can use linux `sed` to rearrange the data to be as follows:

```
[root@]# kubectl config get-contexts | tr -s " " | sed -e "s/ /,/g"
CURRENT,NAME,CLUSTER,AUTHINFO,NAMESPACE
*,kubernetes-admin@kubernetes,kubernetes,kubernetes-admin,
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm on windows, do you know a powershell alternative?

Comment: I am not familiar with poweshell, but let me tell you what above command is doing in case you want to try in poweshell. It is first replacing multiple blank space to single space in output(`tr -s " "`) and then replacing the single space with the comma (`sed -e "s/ /,/g"`)